# How to select correct destination in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to run the 'blank project' found at, 
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/

It's supposed to add the StanfordCPPLib to Xcode (I'm using 4.6) and I'm guessing Stanford templates as well.

Getting error message :
(Xcode cannot run using the selected destination -
choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this system)

I've been trying different architectures but all give me the same error.

Any ideas what I'm missing to get this to work?
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running C++ On Mac:

```
« Open Xcode.
« Xcode-> File -> New ->Project
« Select Command line tool. See image for more clear information.
« Just edit your code in main.cpp then Run.
```

[image]